# Angular: Cannot get ElementRef property

Tags: angular, view, init

I have the following code cloning *this.child* into *obj* in *ngAfterViewInit* method:

```js
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `<input [value]="value">`,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() value: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<child [value]="value" #child></child>',
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = 'Some value';

  @ViewChild('child') child: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var obj: any = {};
    for (let prop in this.child)
      obj[prop] = (this.child as any)[prop];
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit', obj);
    // console.log('ngAfterViewInit', this.child.value); // but this line doesn't work!
  }
}
```

Please, see the source https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhacx7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

It works fine and logged *obj* contains *value* property! But when I uncomment the last line of *ngAfterViewInit* method, it crashes with error:
*Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'*

I have tried *this.child.nativeElement.value* but this one leads to another error:
*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')*

So, *value* property "**does not** exist in *this.child*" but it **does** exist in *obj* (a clone of the former!). Why is it so?

And why do I bother myself with "clone operations"? Because when I simply logged *this.child* into the console it **did** contain *value* property! I thought, maybe it was added **after** *ngAfterViewInit* but **before** logging to the console? That is why I copied the state of *this.child* that it had **during** *ngAfterViewInit*.

So, please, can somebody explain:

1. Why does the linked code not work?
2. Why view elements are not initialized with their input parameters before the moment *ngAfterViewInit*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `child` is of type `ChildComponent`, not `ElementRef`:

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h8wv5x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
export class AppComponent {
  value = 'Some value';

  @ViewChild('child') child: ChildComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var obj: any = {};
    for (let prop in this.child)
      obj[prop] = (this.child as any)[prop];
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit', obj);
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit', this.child.value);
  }
}
```

So that cloning of data isn't necessary, the value has been set, it's just that TypeScript was complaining that `ElementRef` doesn't have the property `value`, which it doesn't.

Comment: That is simply amazing! :))) Thank you a lot!

Comment: Funny fact: value property was really copied during cloning! So, it seems like for-in loop "goes beyond type curtains". Probably, because "obj.value" gets checked when TS gets compiled into JS whereas for-in loop doesn't get changed.